# How can I tell a ContextMenu to place itself relatively to its control and not the cursor?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, contextmenu

I have a button with a default command and a context menu for other available commands:

```
<Button Content="Do this" Height="23" Width="75" Command="local:MyCommands.ThisCommand">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Do this" Command="local:MyCommands.ThisCommand" />
            <MenuItem Header="Do that" Command="local:MyCommands.ThatCommand" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

By default, the context menu appears starting at the hot spot of the cursor:

[image]

However, I'd like it to appear at a fixed relative position, beneath the button (fake, edited screenshot):

[image]

Setting the context menu's `Placement`, `PlacementRectangle` and `PlacementTarget` properties doesn't seem to do anything; the context menu insists on hanging off the cursor wherever I right-click my button. Worse, focusing the button and hitting the [menu key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_key) causes the context menu to sit in front of the button, blocking it completely.

So, how exactly do I specify that the context menu should appear beneath the button?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Check out Remarks under [ContextMenu.Placement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placement.aspx)

and try this

```
<Button Content="Do this" Height="23" Width="75" 
     ContextMenuService.Placement="Bottom"
     Command="local:MyCommands.ThisCommand">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Do this" Command="local:MyCommands.ThisCommand" />
            <MenuItem Header="Do that" Command="local:MyCommands.ThatCommand" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why setting `Placement` on the `ContextMenu`  doesn't work?

Comment: @BoltClock I'm not sure. But check out the Remarks section of [`ContextMenu.Placement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contextmenu.placement.aspx) which states to set `ContextMenuService.Placement`

Comment: The Remarks section happens to have the answer: "When the `ContextMenu` is assigned to the `FrameworkElement.ContextMenu` or `FrameworkContentElement.ContextMenu` property, the `ContextMenuService` changes this value of this property when the `ContextMenu` opens." Now everything falls into place.