# Placing a Context Menu relative to button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to do exactly what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774442/how-can-i-tell-a-contextmenu-to-place-itself-relatively-to-its-control-and-not-t), except with a Rectangle instead of a Button.  I did what is described in the answer (among many other things), and I cannot get it to display as shown relative to the rectangle (which, in my case is being used by a button).

I am using a rectangle as a button because I didn't like the mouseover effects of a button and it seemed easier to just use a rectangle rather than building a custom button.  As a note, I had this same problem even when I was using a button, in Expression Blend 4.

This is the XAML for my rectangle:

```
        <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MouseDown="MenuClicked" Height="55" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="135" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,1,0,0" ContextMenuService.Placement="Bottom">
        <Rectangle.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu x:Name="Menu" >

                <MenuItem x:Name="LoadXML" Header="Load XML" Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="BrowseXML"/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="SaveXML" Header="Save XML" Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="SaveXML"/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="SaveBinary" Header="Save Binary" Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="SaveBinary"/>
                <MenuItem x:Name="SaveText" Header="Save Text" Command="{Binding Command}" CommandParameter="SaveText"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Rectangle.ContextMenu>

        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/Logo.png" Stretch="Uniform" />
        </Rectangle.Fill>

    </Rectangle>
```

This still displays the contextmenu directly next to the point of mouse click.  If I set Placement to bottom within the Context Menu code, rather than adding the ContextMenuService bit to the Rectangle, it displays it at the bottom or top relative to the entire window.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

EDIT: I am also using a method to enable left-clicking of the rectangle.  On MouseDown, it calls this method:

```
    private void MenuClicked(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Menu.PlacementTarget = this;
        Menu.IsOpen = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `ContextMenuService.PlacementTarget` property so the framework knows which element the context menu should be positioned relative to, e.g.:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" ContextMenuService.PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" ... />
```

Just add that property to your Rectangle declaration.  When combined with `ContextMenuService.Placement="Bottom"`, the context menu will appear at the bottom as you intended.

**EDIT:** Since you are opening the menu programatically, you need to set the `Placement` and `PlacementTarget` properties directly on the menu itself.  The attached properties from `ContextMenuService`, when set on the menu's owner, will only take effect if the context menu is opened by conventional means, e.g., a right click.  In your MouseDown handler, you are setting `PlacementTarget = this;`, but you should be setting `PlacementTarget = rectangle;`.

Comment: I did this, such that my rectangle declaration now looks like this:         
     <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" HorizontalAlignment="Left" MouseDown="KetraMenuClicked" Height="55" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="135" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="0,1,0,0" 
       ContextMenuService.Placement="Bottom" ContextMenuService.PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"> and it's still appearing at the point of the click. :[

Comment: Are you opening the menu programmatically or simply by right-clicking the rectangle?

Comment: Well, I have that MouseDown command that I'm using to enable left-clicking of the rectangle as well.  Is that what's causing the problem?  I'll add the routine I'm using to the OP.

Comment: Whenever I try to use PlacementTarget within the actual Rectangle, I get an "The TypeConverter for "UIElement" does not support converting from a string" error.  The current exact text I have is PlacementTarget="rectangle", but it seems to not like PlacementTarget there at all.  Any ideas?  Thanks a lot for your help so far, by the way.

Comment: You can set it in your C# event handler, or you can try setting it to `{Binding ElementName=rectangle}`, but that may not work due to quirkiness in Xaml name scopes.