# ContextMenu Placement

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I'm trying to put my ContextMenu below my UserControl without success:

- I've created an Usercontrol "Bouton_Accueil"
- In my code I've created a ContextMenu
- I've added a MouseDown event on my Bouton_Accueil
- In the MouseDown I've put "contextMenu.IsOpen = true"

But the contextMenu is always appears near the mouse cursor and not under my Control.

Here is my code :

Main Page :

```
<pm:Bouton_Accueil  x:Name="grid_manager" ContextMenuService.Placement="Bottom"   Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Column="0">

        </pm:Bouton_Accueil>
```

In my code :

```
ContextMenu sousMenuManager = new System.Windows.Controls.ContextMenu();
            sousMenuManager.Style = (Style)FindResource("StyleContext");
            sousMenuManager.Width = 133;
            this.grid_manager.ContextMenu = sousMenuManager;
            ContextMenuService.SetPlacement(this.grid_manager, System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Bottom);

public void MouseDown(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                sousMenuManager.IsOpen = true;
        }
```

I have the same issue as this post : [How can I tell a ContextMenu to place itself relatively to its control and not the cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774442/how-can-i-tell-a-contextmenu-to-place-itself-relatively-to-its-control-and-not-t)

How can I just tell my ContextMenu to place itself below my Control ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this, instead ContextMenuService.Placement on button, Set Placement on contextmenu itself like

```
         sousMenuManager.Placement = PlacementMode.Bottom;
```

and in mousedown handler set the placementtarget for the context menu to your grid_manager

```
        sousMenuManager.PlacementTarget = grid_manager;
        sousMenuManager.IsOpen = true;
```